# Elementor plugin in Wordpress not working even when increase memory limit is done

Tags: wordpress, elementor, web-development-server

I am just new in webdev and I've been trying to use Elementor as my builder but it seems that it is not working on my wp. I have increased the memory limit and there are no other plugins running in my wp. Also, when I visit the site from wp, "edit with elementor" does not appear even when "Switch Editor Loader Method" is enabled. When I click "create new page" from elementor, it's just stuck to the loading screen and nothing happens.

hoping someone can help me. thanks a lot!

I tried increasing memory limit and deactivate all other plugins except Elementor

Answer (score 1):

These are some possible solutions :

Clear your browser cache and cookies, as well as your WordPress site's cache, as this can sometimes cause conflicts with the plugin.

Make sure that your version of WordPress, Elementor and all other plugins and themes are up-to-date.

Check your server and browser console for any error messages. These error messages can give you clues as to what might be causing the issue.

Make sure that you have the necessary PHP and MySQL version as per the requirement of the elementor.

Check your site's error logs to see if there are any issues with the plugin or theme that you're using.

Try disabling all other plugins except Elementor and see if that resolves the issue.

Try switching to a default WordPress theme like Twenty Twenty to see if that resolves the issue.

Try reinstalling the elementor plugin and see if it resolves the issue.

Try disabling the "Switch Editor Loader Method" option and see if that resolves the issue.

Check the server settings if the server can handle the load of the elementor plugin.

Comment: Where did you get this list from?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your Wordpress and/or PHP version is compatible with the current Elementor plugin? These are the minimum requirements for running elementor:

- WordPress 5.2 or a more recent version
- PHP 7 or a more recent version
- MySQL 5.6 or a more recent version
- A WordPress memory limit of at least 128 MB

Also there's a handy list of plugin conflicts with elementor here:
https://elementor.com/help/known-plugin-conflicts/